# tree view recursive template angular data from REST API

Tags: angular, treeview, angular2-template

Following this post :
[Best approach to create recursive treeview dynamically from data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522394/best-approach-to-create-recursive-treeview-dynamically-from-data-api/42208872#42208872)

I am able to create the recursive tree view from REST API. See Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LJhAHne4zA6H0lFog1OI

But there is a problem which I am not able to solve is that. Whenever I Click on the `+` icon the form get repeated again. I do not want the form to get repeated on every click on `+`. I want to transfer the value/name which is associated with the `+` icon to the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to move out the form from `ContentListComponent` to `AppComponent` or wrap it with an `*ngIf="expr"` where the `expr` is only true where you want the form to be shown (perhaps only if it's the root node)

Comment: I moved the form to AppComponent and that works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the form out of `ContentListComponent`, for example to `AppComponent` then it won't be repeated for each node.

Comment: Hi, If I delete some children from the tree on runtime then I don't want to refresh the complete tree and only want to refresh that node and show the new data from the REST API. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to refresh the complete tree. Perhaps you are replacing an array instead of just adding/removing items. When an array used in `*ngFor` is replaced, the whole list is re-rendered.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Hi, How can i create a pipe filter in app.component.ts file which filters data by "Name". Example code could be seen in the above [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJhAHne4zA6H0lFog1OI?p=preview).